# Removing the drop shadow from a Scaffold AppBar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, shadow, appbar, flutter-widget

Is there a way to remove the drop shadow under the app bar (AppBar class) when using a Scaffold widget in Flutter?

Answer (score 301, accepted):

Looking at the `AppBar` constructor, there's an `elevation` property that can be used to set the height of the app bar and hence the amount of shadow cast. Setting this to zero removes the drop shadow:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('My App Title'),
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('Hello World'),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: It is useful to me.

Answer (score 42):

I have tried something it might help you

```
AppBar(
backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
bottomOpacity: 0.0,
elevation: 0.0,
),
```

Check this out

Answer (score 23):

If you want to remove the shadow of all app bars without repeating code, just add a `AppBarTheme` property with `elevation: 0` to your app theme (`ThemeData`), inside your `MaterialApp` widget:

```
// This code should be located inside your "MyApp" class, or equivalent (in main.dart by default)
return MaterialApp(
  // App Theme:
  theme: ThemeData(
    // ••• ADD THIS: App Bar Theme: •••
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      elevation: 0, // This removes the shadow from all App Bars.
    )
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 5):

Seems that recent Flutter versions (3.3/3.7+) introduced a new parameter called `scrolledUnderElevation`:

```dart
AppBar(
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  bottomOpacity: 0.0,
  elevation: 0.0,
  // New parameter:
  scrolledUnderElevation: 0,
);
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this! I was going crazy that the normal `elevation` parameter didn't remove the background shadow even though my background color was transparent!